# Python and py2exe - Implicitely Importing Modules

Tags: python, import, module, wxpython, py2exe

I've used py2exe several times in the past to create *.exe files for my python programs.  However, I'm getting an error this time.  I think I know what the issue is, but I don't know how to resolve it.

I have a handful of wx.Panels in a subfolder and it could be a variable amount, so I import them via a function that finds the *.py files in the folder and calls the function below to actually import each panel.

In normal python, this works well.  However, py2exe leaves these files out.  I assume that because they are not explicitly imported, py2exe doesn't believe they are needed.  Is there a solution to this?  Some option in py2exe that I'm unaware of?

Thanks!

```
# module = Module to be imported (string)
# folder = Folder containing the module (string)
def import_module(module, folder=None):
   if folder is None:
      return __import__(module)
   return getattr(__import__('%s.%s' % (folder.replace(os.path.sep, '.'),
      module)), module)


...within some other function...
modules = [import_module(os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]), 'Panels') for filename in glob.glob('Panels//*.py')]
```

**EDIT**

I'm adding a sample setup.py script I've used.  But I've used probably 20 different variations and several completely different scripts (what I could find on the internet).  Note that one requirement is that it is completely self-contained in one executable file.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8.12.1")
import wx
import wx.lib.pubsub

includes = []
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
packages = ['wx.lib.pubsub']
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
                'tk84.dll']

import glob
my_data_files = [('Panels', glob.glob('Panels/*.py'))]

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
                          "optimize": 2,
                          "includes": includes,
                          "excludes": excludes,
                          "packages": packages,
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "bundle_files": 2,
                          "dist_dir": "dist",
                          "xref": False,
                          "skip_archive": False,
                          "ascii": False,
                          "custom_boot_script": '',
                         }
              },
    zipfile = None,
    #data_files = my_data_files,
    windows=['Main.py']
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution for my issue.  In my setup.py file, I replaced the 'includes = []' line with:

```
includes = ['Panels.%s' % os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]) for
        filename in glob.glob('Panels//*.py')]
```

In my code where I use the 'import_module' function, it used to use that glob to import the modules within the Panels directory.  Instead, I've hard-coded a list of modules to include.

This isn't the exact solution I wanted (I don't want to hard-code that list of panels), but it does seem to work.  Unless I discover anything better, this is what I'll continue to use.